# how to make different applications, ports and credentials to a single port and login credential

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

i have different applications and different ports and login credentials..i need to have only one port and single login credential for administrator.

Note: i am using IIS-7, VS-2013 and SQL server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using asp.net MVC.
You can host application on different ports as virtual directories.
While logging in set cookie as follows :

```
if (Users.AuthenticateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: I have different applications and ports and credentials.. i need to make it possible to control all my applications from a single login and Port on Main Dashboard, with out any other credentials and ports conflicts on every app.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use single port or multiple ports? If you want to use multiple ports than you can use machine key section in each of your web.config file. Let me know if you need code for it.

Comment: i want to use single port for different applications.

Comment: Then you will have to use virtual directories or different folders for each application.